# XMLHttpRequest is not working in the WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to send a variable to the server, using XMLHttpRequest.

I tested it on local on a non-Wordpress file and it works. But on production, on my Wordpress file, the onreadystatechange AJAX status doesn't get to 200.

Is there anything I need to be aware when XMLHttpRequesting in Wordpress?

I have the following code for sending data to the server using XMLHTTP Request but it's not working I don't know why? I'm getting the following error:

**VM704:1 POST http://localhost/amt/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)**

here is my WordPress code:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_csv_file', 'csv_file');

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_csv_file', 'csv_file');

function csv_file()
{
if($_POST['rtype'] == 'enr_data'){
        set_time_limit(0);
        ob_implicit_flush(true);
        ob_end_flush();

        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            //Hard work!!
            sleep(1);
            $p = ($i + 1) * 10; //Progress
            $response = array('message' => $p . '% complete. server time: ' . date("h:i:s", time()),
                'progress' => $p);

            echo json_encode($response);
        }

        sleep(1);
        $response = array('message' => 'Complete',
            'progress' => 100);

        echo json_encode($response);

        die();
        }
}
```

```js
function ajax_stream() {
            if (!window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                alert("Your browser does not support the native XMLHttpRequest object.");
                return;
            }
            try {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.previous_text = '';
                xhr.responseType = "text";

                xhr.onerror = function() {
                    alert("[XHR] Fatal Error.");
                };
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    try {
                        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                            alert('[XHR] Done')
                        } else if (xhr.readyState > 2) {
                            var new_response = xhr.responseText.substring(xhr.previous_text.length);
                            var result = JSON.parse(new_response);

                            document.getElementById("divProgress").innerHTML += result.message + '<br />';
                            document.getElementById('progressor').style.width = result.progress + "%";

                            xhr.previous_text = xhr.responseText;
                        }
                    } catch (e) {
                        alert("[XHR STATECHANGE] Exception: " + e);
                    }
                };
                var data = "action=csv_file&rtype=enr_data";
                xhr.open("POST", ajaxurl, true);
                xhr.send(data);
                console.log(xhr);
            } catch (e) {
                alert("[XHR REQUEST] Exception: " + e);
            }
        }
```

```css
#divProgress {
            border: 2px solid #ddd;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 265px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            overflow: auto;
            background: #f5f5f5;
        }
        
        #progress_wrapper {
            border: 2px solid #ddd;
            width: 321px;
            height: 20px;
            overflow: auto;
            background: #f5f5f5;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        
        #progressor {
            background: #07c;
            width: 0%;
            height: 100%;
            -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
            -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
            -o-transition: all 1s linear;
            transition: all 1s linear;
        }
        
        .demo_container {
            width: 680px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 30px;
            background: #FFF;
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
        
        .my-btn,
        .my-btn2 {
            width: 297px;
            margin-top: 22px;
            float: none;
            display: block;
        }
        
        h1 {
            font-size: 22px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        
        .float_left {
            float: left;
        }
        
        .float_right {
            float: right;
        }
        
        .demo_container::after {
            content: "";
            clear: both;
            display: block;
        }
        
        .ghost-btn.active {
            border: 2px solid #D23725;
            color: #D23725;
        }
        
        .ghost-btn {
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;
            border: 2px solid #3b8dbd;
            line-height: 15px;
            color: #3b8dbd;
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
            -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            -moz-background-clip: padding;
            border-radius: 3px;
            background-clip: padding-box;
            font-size: 15px;
            padding: .6em 1.5em;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
            transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
            background: #ffffff;
            -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
            box-sizing: content-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            zoom: 1;
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            position: relative;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        
        .ghost-btn:hover {
            -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease;
            -moz-transition: 0.2s ease;
            -o-transition: 0.2s ease;
            transition: 0.2s ease;
            background-color: #3b8dbd;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        
        .ghost-btn:focus {
            outline: none;
        }
        
        .ghost-btn.active {
            border: 2px solid #D23725;
            color: #D23725;
        }
        
        .ghost-btn.active:hover {
            border: 2px solid #D23725;
            background: #FFF;
        }
        
        .method_wrappers {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="demo_container">
        <div class='method_wrappers'>
            <a class='ghost-btn active' href='#'>XHR Method</a>
            <a class='ghost-btn' href='../example2/index.html'>Iframe Method</a>
        </div>
        <h1>AJAX progress bar for PHP script without polling (XHR method)</h1>
        <div class='float_left'>
            <h3>Progress Bar</h3>
            <div id='progress_wrapper'>
                <div id="progressor"></div>
            </div>
            <a onclick="ajax_stream();" class='my-btn'>Start Ajax Streaming</a>
        </div>
        <div class='float_right'>
            <h3>Log</h3>
            <div id="divProgress"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you declare the ajaxurl var properly?? I don't see it declared in your code

Comment: Did you try to run it after clearing your cache?

Comment: @Rafsun Chowdhury, Yes it's correct did you see the Error text added above.
that's the url:
http://localhost/amt/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Comment: It's hard for me to understand the goal here.  At the very least I can say you should be validating each request with a `nonce` within the PHP.

Comment: @GFargo I just has 400 error this means the request is not sent to the server side.

Answer (score 3):

When using an XHR instead of a jQuery/AJAX request, I found it's actually easier and more reliable to append the `action` to the `ajaxurl`.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = ajaxurl + '?action=csv_file';

xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
```

The method of passing data to the request varies a bit, but 95% of the time I use a simple object to query string function:

```
// Convert an Object into a Query String
function objectToQueryString(obj){
    return Object.keys(obj).map(key => key + '=' + obj[key]).join('&');
}
```

Which in practice will turn a simple data object

```
var data = {
    'post_id': ajax_object.post_id,
    'rtype': 'enr_data',
    'field': element.getAttribute('data-field'),
};
```

into a simple query string:

```
post_id=1234&rtype=enr_data&field=bar
```

This lets me pass the data off as a string posted to the target function:

```
var dataString = objectToQueryString( data );
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(dataString);
```

For larger or more complex tasks you can actually effectively wrap the whole thing in a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) as well, which I'll do if for instance I need to upload a handful of files and pass those along one by one for resizing.

Comment: var url = ajaxurl + '?action=csv_file'; // worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The right solution would be to use "encodeURIComponent". Which correctly transcodes all strings and characters. The function will be:

```js
function encodeURI(obj) {
  var result = '';
  var splitter = '';
  if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
      result += splitter + key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]);
      splitter = '&';
    });
  }
  return result;
},
```

End then use it in your request:

```js
var data = {
  action: 'your action',
  data: JSON.stringify(data)
};

let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
request.send(encodeURI(data));
```